# Encode::HanExtra cannot be installed on Heroku (enc2xs not found)

Tags: perl, heroku, cpan

I am attempting to build a Perl app on Heroku, which requires the module Encode::HanExtra. I'm not sure if it matters, but I am using [this unofficial buildpack](https://github.com/miyagawa/heroku-buildpack-perl) and the requirement is specified in the cpanfile with `requires 'Encode::HanExtra';`. The version of Perl being used is v5.16.3.

Whenever cpanm attempts to configure the module, it errors with

```
   Entering Encode-HanExtra-0.23
   Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
   Running Makefile.PL
   Configuring Encode-HanExtra-0.23 ... enc2xs not found! at Makefile.PL line 46.
   ! Configure failed for Encode-HanExtra-0.23. See /app/.cpanm/work/1507137797.173/build.log for details.
```

Perl already has Encode included since it is a core module, and therefore should have enc2xs. I tried forcing a download of the latest version of Encode to see if it resolved the problem, but it didn't. So I'm guessing there is a problem with how the module finds enc2xs, somehow.

From googling the error message I can see that other Encode modules have had similar errors which were patched, but I am not sure if they are actually the same problem as this one.

I am not so familiar with debugging problems installing CPAN modules, so I would appreciate any pointers. My plan is to look at Makefile.pl if the module has one. FWIW I can install this module on Strawberry Perl just fine. I only have the problem on this Heroku build.

Comment: Re "*and therefore should have enc2xs*', Is this a self-installed `perl`, or the system `perl`? Lots of unix distros leave parts of `perl` out of the standard install, and have you install them using the system's package manager.

Comment: This is a system perl. I explicitly added `requires 'Encode', '2.92';` to the cpanfile (and saw it get installed). However, it is worth noting that cpanm attempted to install Encode::HanExtra before it attempted to install Encode, so maybe it did not help. However, I don't see any way in the cpanfile documentation to force a particular order of installation.

Comment: So did you search your system's package manager for a package that contains `enc2xs`? Did you search the filesystem for `enc2xs` in case it's in a directory that's not in you PATH?

Comment: As for order, Encode 2.92 is only guaranteed to be installed before Encode-HanExtra if it's a dependency of Encode-HanExtra. (Encode-HanExtra surely does have a dependency on Encode, but apparently not Encode 2.92.)

Comment: That is an interesting question about my system's package manager. I am using RHEL 7. I never expected that they would cut out parts of Perl and require them to be installed separately. But it looks like that is what happened: In yum package manager, there is a package available `perl-Encode.x86_64 : Character encodings in Perl` which might give me what I want. Unfortunately you have to be root to update it, and I don't think that's allowed (checking).

Comment: If I can't become root, then I guess my options are 1) Try to improve the buildpack so that it downloads a full copy of Perl from somewhere, instead of using system Perl. 2) Figure out how to get Encode to be installed before Encode::HanExtra. I might be able to do this by having numbered cpanfiles (cpanfile1, cpanfile2) and modifying the buildpack's configure script to go through them one by one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155978/discussion-between-stephen-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by modifying the configure script in the buildpack to explicitly install Encode before processing the cpanfile (`cpanm Encode@2.92`).

Still not sure why system Perl was mangled like this, but glad to have it working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install library "perl-Encode-devel"

`yum install perl-Encode-devel`